# Error on asp.net membership login

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am using asp.net forms authentication on login on my application.Wheni log in at first. i get this error "**(localhost:14078/default.aspx)** " **The resource cannot be found.**
In my application i dont have a page named default page ,All my pages are in a folder.Have tried but i cannot locate where the source of error comes from because when i click back in the browser to get to login page again and enter the login details for a second time,the user is now redirected to the correct page.Can someone explain to me this error?

Here is my login code

```
    protected void Login1_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(Login1.UserName);
        if (Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            if (Roles.IsUserInRole("Admin"))
            {

                Response.Redirect("~/Adminstrator/Data.aspx");


            }

            if (Roles.IsUserInRole("Students"))
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/Students/Results.aspx");


            }





        }

    }
```

Comment: Well, if you are trying to browse to a page called default.aspx, and it does not exist, what are you expecting to occur?

Comment: @OldProgrammer Not that way,i dont have that page in my code,here is the scenario,i can run the application first time and it will not throw that error and will direct user to that page based on his roles.When i log out and login again with the same credentials,i will get that error,have not added a page default.aspx

Comment: Can you check in your login.aspx page and your web.config file to see what the "Failed login" redirect URL is? I suspect this is the issue.

Comment: Possibly a silly suggestion, have you tried loading the login page for the first time and hitting CTRL + F5 to completely refresh the page?

Answer (score 0):

There is a thing called "Start Page" in any ASP.NET classic Web Application.

The "Start Page" can be chosen by right clicking an **aspx** file in the Solution Explorer and click "Set As Start Page".

[image]

The "Start Page" does not entirely need to exist for the whole project to compile and be deployable i.e. you can discover the hard truth at runtime.

But then again it is only a matter of where you want your browser to go when you hit F5.

Possible resolutions:

- manually navigate to "localhost:14078/Students/Results.aspx" after you see the error
- assign a fresh, existing "Start Page" in the IDE

Comment: I don't think the start page should affect the redirected page once he log's in?

Comment: Yes but it might be the case that the original navigation was indeed made towards the Start Page(in that case, the Forms Authentication mechanism will not worry about the missing target -- it will only notice that the requested url is not mentioned in the "No authentication required" areas of the application configuration file and only after the login will be fully executed, will the Forms Authentication mechanisms cause a redirect to the initial resource which is missing).I assumed that when the asker said "When i log in at first" he or she meant <<When I start up the project by hitting F5>>.

Comment: @EduardDumitru I have figured out what the problem was,Login view was not defined in my master page.I added login view and then did set the Role groups feature.Its working now

Answer (score 0):

The problem was  the absence of default page.I created a default page and the error was solved.